# Django Update Form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that users enter in information on locations. I'm trying to make an update form so users can click the update button on a location and the update form comes populated with the data thats already there for that location. I have followed the Django docs but I am getting a blank screen. I am unsure how to get it to reference which location to update. Here is what I have so far.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    # Details on location
```

views.py

```
    def locations(request):
        return render_to_response('locations/locations.html', {'locations': Location.objects.all() })

    def location(request, location_id=1):
        return render_to_response('locations/location.html', {'location': Location.objects.get(id=location_id) })

    def create(request):
        if request.POST:
            form = LocationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin/locations/all/')
        else:
            form = LocationForm()

        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))

        args['form'] = form

        return render_to_response('locations/create_location.html', args)

def edit_location(request): 

    if request.POST:
        form = LocationUpdate(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin/locations/all/')
    else:
        form = LocationUpdate()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('locations/location_update.html', args)
```

forms.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from models import Location

class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        exclude = ('timestamp', 'updated')

class LocationUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Location
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

url.py

```
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/location/update/$', 'assessments.views.edit_location'),
```

location_update.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="update" />
    </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

or should it go in location.html. If i add it in there i get a `CSRF verification failed` error

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>ID:</dt>
                <dd>{{ location.id }}</dd>
                <br />
                <dt>Company:</dt>
                <dd>{{ location.company }}</dd>
                <dt>Address:</dt>
                <dd>{{ location.address }}</dd>
                <dt>Town:</dt>
                <dd>{{ location.town_city }}</dd>
                <dt>County:</dt>
                <dd>{{ location.county }}</dd>
                <dt>Telephone:</dt>
                <dd>{{ location.tel }}</dd>
                ###### ect #####
    </div>
</div>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="update" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Is that the full code of your location_update.html? You're not perhaps extending from another template?

Comment: For testing purposes its just got the html header and body tags. Once it is working i will add it to a template. Does it need to be part of the location.html?

Comment: I don't understand that reply. Is that the full code of location_update.html? If not, please post the full code. Also, explain *exactly* what you see. Do you get anything showing at all? What do you see when you do View Source?

Comment: Edited the question to include more info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see a few problems:

1. Your update view is exactly like your create view.
2. You are passing the ***UpdateView class*** as the form in your update view.

If you are going to use an update view, you don't need to wrap it in another view or use it as a form, it is entirely self-contained.

In your *`views.py`* (not `forms.py`):

```
from .models import Location
from .forms import LocationForm

class LocationUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Location
    template_name = 'locations/location_update.html'
    form_class = LocationForm
    success_url = '/accounts/loggedin/locations/all/'
```

In your `urls.py`:

```
url('location/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', LocationUpdateView.as_view(),
                                     name='location-update'),
```

If you wire it up like this, you need to call the update view with the primary key of the location object you want to update. This will make sure that the form is populated with the data; so call it like this `<a href="{% url 'location-update' pk=1 %}">update location id 1</a>`.

If you do not want to use the class based view, then your view should be updated to load the data first, populate the form, then send the form to the user, and just like the UpdateView above, you need to pass in the primary key (or other reference), to load the object for which you are editing the record:

```
def update_location(request, pk=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Location, pk=pk)
    form = LocationForm(request.POST or None,
                        request.FILES or None, instance=obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('/accounts/loggedin/locations/all/')
    return render(request, 'locations/location_update.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Also helped with other areas of django I was unsure on. One last thing is that I am getting an error when I click to post the update 'No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.' I used the first method you suggested