# Django set random password for user once

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have created an extended User model and a form to register it. Since the form is filled out by an admin and not a user, the UserCreationForm has a random password generator to fill out password1 and 2, then set new password. This is great for a new user, but every time an admin edits the user profile, it will set a new password. I've looked at a few dozen examples here and on big G but can't seem to find a usable solution to know if the user has a password set.

I am re-using this form for update view, which is where I don't want the random password to be generated again. I tried doing the same if statement check as the username but it doesn't work the same way as the auth\form.py user.set_password is looking for password1.

```
class EmployeeRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2',
                                                                           'placeholder': 'Email address'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2',
                                                               'placeholder': 'First name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 'Last name'}))

    password1 = None
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean(self):
        password = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10,
                                                     allowed_chars='abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789')
        self.cleaned_data['password1'] = password
        self.cleaned_data['password2'] = password

        return super().clean()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)

        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if user.username == '':
            if len(user.first_name.split()) and len(user.last_name.split()) > 1:
                username = f'{"".join(user.first_name.split()[:2])}{"."}{"".join(user.last_name.split())}'
            elif len(user.first_name.split()) > 1:
                username = f'{"".join(user.first_name.split()[:2])}{"."}{user.last_name}'
            elif len(user.last_name.split()) > 1:
                username = f'{user.first_name}{"."}{"".join(user.last_name.split())}'
            else:
                username = f'{user.first_name}{"."}{user.last_name}'
            username = username.lower()
            user.username = username
        
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**Update**

Here is the profile_edit view where I verify the details of an existing user and save changes made through the form.

```
@login_required()
def profile_edit(request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Used for updating the Employee profile
    """
    employee = Employee.objects.get(slug=slug)
    employee_user = User.objects.get(id=employee.user.id)
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=employee)
    user_form = EmployeeRegistrationForm(request.POST or None, instance=employee_user)
    if 'cancel' in request.POST:
        return redirect('corehr:employees')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=employee)
        user_form = EmployeeRegistrationForm(request.POST or None, instance=employee_user)
        if form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            user_form.save()
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'{employee.get_full_name}{" was updated successfully."}')
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('corehr:profile', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the errors listed below')
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=employee)
        user_form = EmployeeRegistrationForm(request.POST or None, instance=employee_user)
    context = {'form': form, 'user_form': user_form}
    return render(request, 'coreHR/profile_edit.html', context)
```

Comment: can you differentiate between first-time user creation and update method?

Comment: That's the part that I don't know yet, I'm still learning Django.

Comment: So at user creation, there is no user Id and related data, and when you update you have a user and user id (technically an object). At update, you only change the fields which you want to, not necessarily all the data.

Comment: Yup, I understand that part. Is it possible to do a check within the form like User.objects.password_exists or something like that? If yes, where should I plug it in?

Comment: When you update the information about the User, how do you know which user you are dealing with?

Comment: What you are doing is create, you will have to look at the ways for update. Check this   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013270/django-update-form) for an example or you may find few more. You need to use the instance of selected user and then update.

Comment: Don't reuse the same form for updating, do you see many sites allowing you to change passwords _and_ your profile information together? No, because changing the password is a more sensitive task. Also don't generate a random password, just set it to `None` which will cause Django to make an unusable password, and then send them a password reset link.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking the suggestions from Abdul and Ranu. The are both right, so I just created a UserUpdateForm to update the data rather to 're-create' the user again. It all works as smooth as ever.

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2'}),
        }
```

I replaced the reference in the profile_edit view from EmployeeRegistrationForm to UserUpdateForm. This was so simple an I was busting my head trying to work around several complex solutions which were going against the basics.